# Binding Data On Image Src Not Working Properly

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When I select images I change them to base64 and save them inside array inside an object. I want to show them via v-bind:src but they don't.

```
 <script>
    export default {
            data (){
                 return {
                      product:{
                           name:'',
                           description:'',
                           Photo:[]
                          }
                      }
                    },
            methods:{
                 PhotoSelected (e){
                    Here I change photos to base64
                   }
             } 
 </script>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? `Photo[]` this is not how initialize an empty array in an object, you should use `photo: []`

Comment: Here I typed wrong. On sublime text it's ok.

Comment: Please [edit] the question so that it accurately reflects what you have in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through a similar problem related to `base64` image rendering.

You need to append `data:image/jpg;base64,` before your converted image bytes.

```
<img v-bind:src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+{converted image}" />
```

If this doesn't resolve your problem, please update your question with a reproducible example

Comment: But this on is binded at the first by default.

Comment: Sorry, Can you explain more what you want to say with your comment ?

Comment: You said to append it "data:image/jpg;base64" but this one is appended by default.

Comment: Then you probably need to give an example to help you better